# Google Maps reverse geocode doesn't return correct/accurate address

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

So I have this specific address: **Rijtakker 22, Meijel, Netherlands** 
This is just a normal address that is known by Google Maps, as shown at `www.google.nl/maps/place/Rijtakker+22,+5768+Meijel/@51.3482599,5.8857767,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x47c7379f181928e7:0x2a2900b2927e2ebc!8m2!3d51.3482566!4d5.8879654?hl=nl`.

In one of my (ASP.NET) applications I've made a web user control where the user types in an address in a Google Maps-esque field, it features suggestions, does autocompleting, et cetera. All pretty standard and based on default Google Maps API behavior / documentation code samples, it's shown [in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6tjQ.png). As the user selects an address, one or more Marker objects appear on the map. If only one marker is applicable, that marker's position (lat, lng) is written to a hidden field, if multiple markers are applicable, the position (lat, lng) of a marker being clicked is written to the same hidden field. Upon PostBack, a WebRequest is made to a reverse-geocoding URL to retreive all the address information. Once again, all pretty standard. In case of aforementioned address, the lat and lng values returned in the XML are **51.3482464** and **5.8879746999999725**

First weird thing is that when I use a geocoding URL to convert the address to latitude and longitude, I get different results than the markers in my Google Maps user control. The link `maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Rijtakker%2022,%20Meijel,%20Netherlands` returns

```
<location>
    <lat>51.3482464</lat>
    <lng>5.8879747</lng>
</location>
```

Either way, when reverse geocoding both longitude and latitude values return an address range, or in Google API terms a *route*, rather than a speficic *street_address*: **Rijtakker 2-40, 5768 Meijel, Netherlands**. Rather than the actual correct address. Whether I use a reverse geocoding URL (`maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=51.3482464,5.8879746999999725` or `maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=51.3482464,5.8879747`) or I use the map examples in Google Maps API documentation (`developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse`)

What am I doing wrong? Is there some limitation in the (reverse) geocoding process where not every address can be accurately converted?

Comment: Got another weird address: Zilleveld 7, Neeritter, Netherlands. The address is known in Google Maps, but going to http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Zilleveld+7,+Neeritter,+Netherlands returns a route rather than a street address. Could it be that a lot of addresses in the API are still unknown?

Comment: This maybe a situation of [partial_matches](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingResponses)

partial_match indicates that the geocoder did not return an exact match for the original request, though it was able to match part of the requested address. You may wish to examine the original request for misspellings and/or an incomplete address.

This [thread](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80838/how-to-get-accurate-coordinates-from-google-geocoding-services) might also be similar to your predicament.

Comment: The spelling is correct; in the concerning user control, 'suggestions' (Google API) are being used also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal behaviour for results that are `RANGE_INTERPOLATED`

See result's `geometry.location.type`, see the [Developer's Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Results) for what its values mean. In short, Google Maps does not have the building/house **22** in **Rijtakker, Meijel**, but it does have a range of address (**2-40**) and is able to interpolate where 22 would typically be.

Geocoding [Rijtakker 2, Meijel](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3DRijtakker%25202%252C%2520Meijel%252C%2520Netherlands) and [Rijtakker 40, Meijel](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3DRijtakker%252040%252C%2520Meijel%252C%2520Netherlands), results at the start and end of the street.

In contrast, [51.348165,5.887406](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D51.348165%252C5.887406) returns a `ROOFTOP` result.

You may also get a `RANGE_INTERPOLATED` result from reverse geocoding, with a precise address instead of an address range, and that precise address may geocode as a `RANGE_INTERPOLATED` or `ROOFTOP` result, if your latlng is closer to an address range than to the actual building.

Example: [51.347234,5.886687](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D51.347234%252C5.886687) returns "Startebosweg 4, 5768 Meijel", which then [geocodes as a `ROOFTOP` result](http://Startebosweg%204,%205768%20Meijel), and it's location [51.348299,5.886218](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D51.348299%252C5.886218) geocodes to the same `ROOFTOP` result. The gap between the 2 latlngs in this paragraph might be due to a glitch in the basemap data.